# How to call stored procedure with xml parameters using sqlcmd on Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, sqlcmd

On my Ubuntu machine, I need to call a stored procedure which accepts XML input parameter. I am not getting the correct way to call the stored procedure passing the parameter. 
I have tried below commands

```
XML=$(echo "cat doc.xml")
sqlcmd -Q "exec MyStoredProc @Dataxml=$($XML)"
```

Or

```
sqlcmd -Q "exec MyStoredProc @Dataxml=$XML"
```

Or

```
sqlcmd -Q "exec MyStoredProc @Dataxml=$(XML)"
```

But none of these really worked. My sqlcmd version is  17.1.0000.1 Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the XML parameter value as a string literal:

```
sqlcmd -Q "exec MyStoredProc @Dataxml='$XML';"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did work. I marked it accepted. However my XML is pretty big and now it throws "Argument list too long" error. Do you see any workaround for this? the XML size is around 900 KB

Comment: or it may be because xml itself having single quotes making it courrept and sqlcmd treating parts of the XML as the argument list

Comment: @HSharma, true, if single quotes are used to enclose attribute values. Othereise, the XML will include entity reference `&quote;` for single quotes so it won't be misinterpreted by SQLCMD.